# Android google map api v2 error

Tags: android, google-maps

```
public class SunFlowerMap extends Fragment {

      private static final int REQUEST_CODE_FSQ_CONNECT = 200;
      private static final int REQUEST_CODE_FSQ_TOKEN_EXCHANGE = 201;


    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saBundle){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sunflowermap, container, true);



        return rootView;

    }
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Mainifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Social.Movement3"
    android:versionCode="16"
    android:versionName="2.3.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIxxxxxxxxxx"/>
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:name="com.Social.Movement3.ParseApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" >
          <activity
            android:name="com.Social.Movement3.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>  

        <activity
         android:name="com.Social.Movement3.MainActivity"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@style/Theme.Sunflower"> 
           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>       
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"/>
<!--         Parse push Notification -->
               <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
                <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
                  <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                  </intent-filter>
                </receiver>
                <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
                    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
                  <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                    <category android:name="com.Social.Movement3" />
                  </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
 <!--         Parse push Notification -->

    </application>


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

        <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
            android:name="com.Social.Movement3.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.Social.Movement3.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

 <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>       

 <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>



  <uses-permission
     android:name="com.Social.Movement3.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

</manifest>
```

Properties
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Deedx.png
Log
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4wSS.png

I cant figure out what's going on..
I have already add google play service and api key
the log still said I didn't and I have no idea..
the error onCreateView in line:33 is

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xxx, container, false);
```

please help ~thanks

Comment: your manifest should contain the real API key, not with "xxxxx", pleas e check that out.

Comment: yes, i did， I change it before post in stackoverflow, thanks for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `<meta-data>` at wrong place, that must be in  `<application>` element, so You should try like :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name="com.Social.Movement3.ParseApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" >
      <activity
        android:name="com.Social.Movement3.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>  
.
.// You other stuff goes here.
.
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIxxxxxxxxxx"/>
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Referred from [Here](http://blog.iangclifton.com/2010/10/08/using-meta-data-in-an-androidmanifest/)

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Now what type of problem occurs?

Comment: There is same issue and Log after fix meta-data tag before application. http://i.imgur.com/rJFsoXH.png

Comment: ＠Super User, Ｉ success to fix it, thanks a lot, I think is include jar issues on eclipse, I'm not very clear about add jar via build path, sometimes I just need check the box in order and export, sometime I need copy to lib folder, but sometime when I copy to lib folder, Eclipse said I user multiple jar...
In short, thanks for your time...

Comment: Something like this, Log said I have no Google Play Service Lib, but I have already add in http://i.imgur.com/TWhWZdJ.png, Finally, I add to here(http://i.imgur.com/QkdFOTM.png),but not check(http://i.imgur.com/JtTxOS7.png) and Eclipse find my lib, but my facebook lib didnt need to do this...

Comment: @YmowWu It's a thing of great pleasure that your problem is solved in the end :-)